# Meaning of line in the code (scanf)

Tags: c

In my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void flushstdin() 
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

int main () {
    float a, b, c;
    float s=0, ar1=0, ar2=0;
    printf("Inform the value of size A.");
        while(scanf("%f",&a) != 1 || a <= 0){
        printf("Invalid value!");
```

What does "while(scanf("%f",&a) != 1 || a <=0){" means?

Comment: Break the problem down into its smaller pieces and try to figure it out yourself! Surely you can grasp what `while (a <= 0)...` means, and surely you can fill in the pieces to decode `while (condition1 || condition2)...` means. Reading the man page will help you understand the return value of `scanf(...)`. Put these components all together and you've got no need to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, scanf returns either the number of arguments matched in the given pattern (the %f part) read, or a -1 if an EOF was encountered (meaning end of input). Then a <= 0 should be somewhat self explanatory. These two combined this code will result in an input loop until either the user enters a value greater than 0 or nothing at all.

For more information on scanf, check out the docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: "the number of characters read" did you mean: "the number of items of the argument list that have been filled"?

Comment: Nope. The loop ends if a>0.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Also correct, however your method of communication is a bit sparse and next time you could just fix the answer instead of writing a comment like that.

Comment: @Ron E what about this     while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
I'm beggining in programming, and a dude helped me with this code, but I don't understand too much what does that part "    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);" do =(

Answer (score 1):

This attempts to reads a float from stdin and checks whether the float was successfully read (scanf returns the number of arguments successfully read). If a was read successfully, it checks whether a is larger than zero.  It continues until both conditions are false. The second condition will only be evaluated when the first condition is false, i.e. a has been read.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` returns number of elements successfully read and in this case you are expecting the number of elements read to be `1`. If the conversion fails then the value will not be 1 so you print out `invalid value`, the scanned value `a` can't be less that or equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%f",&a) is use for input value in your program , and here your condition is loop keep going until you enter 1 or nagitive value

Answer (score 0):

While scanf returns a float (%f) e.g. 4.535 and stores it into variable a (&a) that is not equal to 1 or (||) a is equal to or less than zero (a<=0)

Comment: `scanf()` does not return a float. I know that's not what you meant, but your choice of wording has different meaning. There is no comparison of `a` equal to 1 in this code (but again, your choice of wording suggests otherwise).